# How to avoid newline at the end of written file

Tags: file, tcl

is there a way in tcl to avoid having the newline at the end of a written file ?

```
puts $file $line
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off, `puts` always writes the last argument you give, followed by a newline unless you also specified the `-nonewline` option.

When writing lines in a loop, where you don't want a newline at the end of just the last line, you're really using `\n` as a line *separator* rather than a line *terminator*. To do that without building all the data in a single string, it is easiest to use an extra variable to hold the separator and have that start out empty.

```
# Initially
set separator ""
```

```
# Inside the loop
puts -nonewline $file $separator$line
set separator "\n"
```

Setting a (hopefully local) variable to a constant value is a small amount of extra work to do per iteration, and it is easy to be sure that this does the right thing.

(Of course, if you were really writing to a file you could also use `seek` or `chan truncate` after the loop to make things patched up. It's harder to do though — “newline” isn't always written as a single byte, depending on the `fconfigure -translation` option — and doesn't work with non-file channels at all. Not recommended in this case!)

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. It works perfectly. The diff doesn't show any difference now between the rewritten file and the original file.

Answer (score 4):

If you already have all the lines in memory:

```
puts -nonewline $file [join $lines \n]
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe:

```
puts -nonewline $file $line
```

Comment: if I do this, I will have all the lines in one line in my file. Remember that it's a loop and I only need nonewline for the last line.

Comment: @user2669068 Your question didn't mention any loop? Could you add your code snippet in your question?

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
puts -nonewline $file "\n$line"
```

Comment: Please edit your previous answer instead of writing another one if there aren't significant changes.